# Regex for single character and empty String(Not white space)

Tags: regex

I have a optional fields in which I have to accept only single character and I should also accept empty string.
Ex:
if I have a middle name field, in which it accepts single char. but in future if he don't want any middle name on his account then I should persist empty to the middle name in the database.

I used the below regexp. but it is not working to accept empty string
`[^$]|[A-Za-z]+`

Could some one help me on this?

Comment: + means 1 or more. ? means 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `^[A-Za-z]?$` (one or zero letters)?

Comment: but can I know what is ? stands here

Comment: @Pradeep It means "match either 0 or 1 occurence of whatever came before it". In your case it means "match either zero or one character". Look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) for more details (btw, if it is working for you, could you mark the answer as accepted - the checkmark on the left side?).

Comment: if I need to add + for the expression.How can I add that?

Comment: Could you please also tell me how if there is multiple characters with empty String acceptable rather than single character

Comment: @Pradeep regarding the comment about adding + to the expression - not sure exactly what you mean. What exactly do you need to match? And as for the last comment, yes, that's what `*` is for, so `^[A-Za-z]*$` will match either zero characters (empty String) or multiple letters (one or more)